# Sumo failed to build routes when work with Veins

Tags: veins, sumo

I have an error when using Veins with Sumo for vehicular network simulation. If I run Sumo alone, the traffic simulation runs well without any error. But when I run Veins simulation together with Sumo, it seems like Sumo have errors with loading the routes file. The Veins simulation continues without loading vehicles from Sumo. The error message from Sumo GUI is as below:

```
***Starting server on port 55693 ***
Loading net-file from 'portland-pearl-district.net.xml'... done (552ms).
Warning: Unused states in tlLogic 'GS_1323183749', program '0' in phase 0 after tl-index -1
Warning: Unused states in tlLogic 'GS_1323183750', program '0' in phase 0 after tl-index -1
Loading additional-files from 'portland-pearl-district.poly.xml'... done (87ms).
Loading done.
Error: The edge '5519430#0' within the route for vehicle '0' is not known.
The route can not be build.
Quitting (on error).
Simulation started with time: 0.00
```

Below is a snapshot of the rou.xml file:

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/routes_file.xsd">
    <vehicle id="0" depart="0.00">
        <route edges="5519430#0 45701315#1 31804683 27479270 39799366 189618243#1 190534275#0 459643631#0 69333880 138671582 73151943#0"/>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle id="1" depart="0.00">
        <route edges="5521280 189781336#0 5535569#0 39799364#2 189618701 418881460 31724224 189618702#0 gneE0 39799365#4 39799365#7 39799365#8 39799365#12 160826987 118957876 118957873 159410080#0 159410080#3 159410080#4 32653964#0"/>
    </vehicle> 
    <vehicle id="2" depart="0.00">
        <route edges="5522371#0 150570455#3 150570455#5 150570455#9 150570455#13 118767064 221226627#0 5522879 189781349"/>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle id="3" depart="0.00">
        <route edges="123622099#2 189781333#1 15915234#1 15915234#2 15915234#5 23592541#0 5535400 189781336#0 5535569#0 39799364#2 189618701 418881460 31724224"/>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle id="4" depart="0.00">
        <route edges="5514406 5519546#0 5519546#1 5519430#0 45701315#1 31804683 27479270 39799366 189618243#1 190534275#0 gneE0 39799365#4 39799365#7 124395214#8 124395214#12 118962440#1 118962440#4"/>
    </vehicle>
    ......
    </routes>
```

What is the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a launchd.xml file for running SUMO via a proxy? Or are you setting the .sumocfg file in your omnetpp.ini file? Maybe you are not running the SUMO simulation you think you are.

Comment: I use launchd.xml as in the veins example. Actually, if I manually create the rou.xml file with only a few routes, the Sumo works well with Veins. But this problem arises when I use a rou.xml file generated by randomTrips.py.

Comment: Have you set an omnetpp.ini parameter to keep the number of vehicles constant or is the vehicle 0 from your error message one that is configured in the .rou.xml file?

Comment: I did not set the number of vehicles in omnetpp.ini. Vehicles are defined in rou.xml file.

Comment: If you can share a zip file of your simulation, I will be happy to take a look. On the face of it, though, everything looks to be in order.